# How take join two datatable in LINQ and extract its value using loop

Tags: linq

I have taken value in two datatable

Dt1

```
EMPID empname  sickleave  casual leave  earned leave
1      john                            1
```

Dt2

```
EmpId  empname  sickleave  casualleave  earned leave
 1      john      5          5           5
```

in dt2 defaul value of leave are give (total leave for a employee)and in dt1 leave taken by employee are given.
so I want to show result in grid in this form like

```
Empname sickleave casualleave earnedleave
john       0/5       0/5          1/5

for this i wrote code like this

 var result = from p in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                 join q in dt2.AsEnumerable() on p.Field<int>("EmpID") equals q.Field<int>("EmpID") into UP
                                 from q in UP.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                 select new
                                 {
                                     EmpID = p.Field<int>("EmpID"),
                                     EmpName = p.Field<string>("EmpName"),

                                     SickLeave = (p.Field<int?>("Sick Leave") ?? 0).ToString() + "/" + (q.Field<int?>("Sick Leave") ?? 0).ToString(),
                                     CasualLeave = (p.Field<int?>("Casual Leave") ?? 0).ToString() + "/" + (q.Field<int?>("Casual Leave") ?? 0).ToString(), 
                                     EarnedLeave = (p.Field<int?>("Earned Leave") ?? 0).ToString() + "/" + (q.Field<int?>("Earned Leave") ?? 0).ToString()
                                 };

                    GridViewLeaveSummary.DataSource = result;
                    GridViewLeaveSummary.DataBind();
```

this code is working fine but i want to make leave dynamic means grid show no of leave according to leave type table (means all leaves field come from datable) because i have to add  different leave type .in this code olny three leaves are given and i have to add more leaves .means in grid no of leaves show acording to the database

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear why your code does not fit your needs. Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: actually i am trying to achieve result which show total no of leave taken by employee and the total no of leave assigned by comapny to that employee. when i coded this the no of leave are fixed that is 3 (sick leave ,casual leave,earned laeve) but now i have to code this dynamic leave type. means no of leave comes from databse may be three or four , or it may be 2 also depends apon database

Comment: Columns in both tables always exactly same? Columns in second data table can contain nulls?

Comment: yes , both table take data from leavetype table at this time three leves are available but its value can be changed.yes second datatable  can contains null. if leave not taken by employee. if second table contains null for any leave it should dispaly 0 .